# Not seeing how to unsubscribe from Meetup emails with certain subject phrases

Tags: email, meetup

Subjects include:

```
Can you make
events coming up soon
Last chance
Join x at y tomorrow
Just scheduled
```

They're all repetitive suggestion emails, for different events, just piling up for days on end in my inbox... none for any event I've RSVP's for. When trying to unsubscribe (from the link at the bottom of the email), I'm having trouble figuring what to disable:

```
Email updates

[the group's name]
Turn on all notifications [a link to click that enables them all]

New event announcements [this I want, just not 6 emails about it]
My RSVP is confirmed
Changes to event time or location
New comments & chat messages
Event reminders
Event rating requests
Event updates from organizers [does this include any of the above email types mentioned?]
New photos uploaded
Someone tags or comments on my photo
Announcement to members about the group
Discussion invitations
```

Most of those options I'm OK with and obviously don't apply... so, what am I supposed to disable to stop getting all of these suggestion emails when I just want to know about new events?

It doesn't work like other sites like Twitter where clicking Unsubscribe for a type of email just unsubscribes me from that type of email.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, I rarely signed up for anything from email, so I turned off:

- New event announcements
- Event reminders
- Announcement to members about the group

for each of my groups. I think "Event reminders" might be the one that's duplicating these messages. Logically we could group them:

- "New event announcements"

  - Just scheduled
- "Event reminders"

  - Can you make
  - events coming up soon
  - Last chance
  - Join x at y tomorrow

but this is just a guess, haven't tested it too deep and have done this setup years ago.

---

Alternatively just leave everything on, and write an email rule in your inbox to auto-delete those messages. GMail can do this easily for example.